# Jenkins pipeline stop job triggering on branch creation event

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

We are using bitbucket server and Jenkins pipeline jobs.
When new branches are created on git and setup to trigger build automatically on ref changes, how to stop running a job on Jenkins on branch creation event??

PS: I don't want to avoid builds on scm changes afterwards.

Comment: When you created the webhook you should mention only on push event.

Comment: @rohitthomas unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: @kagarlickij you will have to give more information than that...are you facing the exact same issue ?

Comment: What I have understood so far is that job has to run in order to list new branch on the multi-branch pipeline job. So I checked at the build number and skipped executing pipeline if it is one.